# Slow adb install speed to AVD

Tags: android, installation, adb, performance

While there is a [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator) is it inherent that adb install is this slow on my i5-2500 machine to an AVD?

```
$ adb install -r foo.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/foo.apk
Success
100 KB/s (37517364 bytes in 364.951s)
```

The apk is 37mb nevertheless, but the transfer speed is so slow.

Is there a way to copy apks for installing in near the native speed of the host os?

Comment: have you tried to copy the file to the sdcard image and then installing it with `pm install`?

Comment: @AlexP. thanks, not yet, I'll try it! Sounds like a good idea.